# Parse JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'd like to parse

```
{"ticker":{"high":31.9099,"low":22.5,"vol":108468,"buy":29.61,"sell":30,"last":29.61}}
```

and end up with:

```
last = 29.61
```

but I don't know where to start parsing python :(

Comment: I really don't understand why these question keep getting asked... typing "parse json python" into google leads straight into the Python `json` package.  From there it should be straightforward.

Comment: @I82Much, [Embrace the non-googlers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers)

Comment: @Mike Pennington: Sure, there's plenty of room for non-googlers. They can use Bing instead. Or they can just fire up their Python library manual contents page and type Ctrl-Fjson

Comment: @Mike thanks for the link to the discussion.  I understand being welcoming etc., but I don't think people's first thought when they hit *any* snag should be to post a new StackOverflow question.  Instead people should invest at least a modicum of effort into finding the answer on their own.  That's my opinion at all.

Comment: @I82Much - if you type 'parse json python' into google, you land at *THIS*  page.

Comment: I was less informed back in 2011 - I understand the utility of these types of questions now.

Answer (score 13):

```
>>> text = '''{"ticker":{"high":31.9099,"low":22.5,"vol":108468,"buy":29.61,"sell":30,"last":29.61}}'''
>>> json.loads(text)
{u'ticker': {u'sell': 30, u'buy': 29.609999999999999, u'last': 29.609999999999999, u'vol': 108468, u'high': 31.9099, u'low': 22.5}}
>>> json.loads(text)[u'ticker'][u'last']
29.609999999999999
```

Or use simplejson with older versions of Python.

Comment: Why is it `u'ticker'` instead of `ticker`?

Comment: @KshitizSharma: Because [`'ticker'` is bytes, not text.](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I thought I should post this here in case someone else finds it useful. There is a nice post here on [Parsing JSON in Python](http://www.jroller.com/evans/entry/parsing_json_with_python) - it is small be shows how you could use it in different scenarios.

Good luck!